# How to Reallocate Memory use by Form on form close

Tags: c#-4.0

I am developing Windows application and when i am calling one form to another form that time memory is goes on increasing

when I am closing My Win form the memory use by that form can not reallocate. memory use by that.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot reallocated / allocate memory in c#. You can only create objects & later assign null to their references so that they would be collected by GC.
In order to better use memory you can override the dispose method of your form and dispose all the objects created inside the form.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing && (components != null)) {
        components.Dispose();
        // dispose your objects. 
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```